# React/Yarn suddenly is non-functional after Microsoft update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, yarnpkg

I recently started using react.js/node with a mongodb connection and I created a working app that I luckily committed and works fine when cloned on other machines. However, something happened on my local machine that disabled yarn, node, and mongo to work locally. I suspect it was a faulty microsoft security patch update that wreaked havoc on my local drive. I reinstalled node and mongo, but react/yarn doesn't work anymore. when I type yarn install, or yarn start at the root I get this error:Error: Cannot find module

```
'C:\Users\jrsil\.yarn\bin\yarn.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

npm install at the root and the client, and I had quite a few people look at this, and we can't figure out what went/is wrong. I suspect that this technical glitch/patch that went through did something to my PC and yarn is no longer putting files in the correct places. Any thoughts as to what happened the last few days that caused all my development work to become non functional would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: tried uninstalling and installing yarn or npm again?

Comment: check your path.

Comment: Thanks. I have C:\Users\jrsil\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin in user path, and C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin in the system path. Are these the correct paths for yarn? And if so, why when I type yarn start, git is looking for C:\Users\jrsil\.yarn\bin\yarn.js (which seems to be a deadend) How can I change git to hit the correct path? It seems to me that if I have node working again, react/yarn should be working as well.